# IDE with syntax highlight support for LESS

Tags: syntax-highlighting, less

Is there any IDE with syntax highlight support for [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)?

Answer (score 36):

Eclipse does not support .less fully (nested rules, single line comments, etc) but you can at least configure it so that it would open .less files and treat them as .css.

Preferences > General > Content Types:
find "CSS" entry and add .less extension.

Then, Preferences > General > Editors > File Assoc:
add .less extension and associate with CSS editor.

Better than nothing, especially if you're into Eclipse world ;)

Comment: Maybe this plugin is an alternative for Eclipse users: http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/ow/eclipse-less.fr.html

Comment: @Alp: That plugin really works well, just installed it and works... haven't tested compiling to CSS in Eclipse though.

Comment: __@Alp__ `Missing requirement: net.vtst.ow.eclipse.less.ui 1.0.19 (net.vtst.ow.eclipse.less.ui 1.0.19) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.xtext.ui 2.2.1' but it could not be found.` Any ideas?

Comment: Note that you lose all comments when you format using this plugin in version 1.0.22

Answer (score 7):

[JetBrains PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) has built-in support for LESS :)

Comment: Which version are you using? Mine supports SASS but not LESS.

Comment: It costs money whether eclipse is free. Also it lacks many good features from it.

Comment: @gaRex Uh it's actually the opposite feature wise. Give it a try, you will forget the anomaly called Eclipse ;P

Comment: @SalmanPK I already tried it for a 30 days. Some things are great, but working with basic things are so bad, that I'm just cryin: vcs/git, searchin, tasks (weak parody on mylyn).

Answer (score 5):

You could use Netbeans plugin for LESS.

In Netbeans 6.9:
tools-> Available Plugins-> LessCSS Module

Version: 1.0.6 Source: Plugin Portal
Plugin Description
This module is to allow for tighter integration of netbeans with LessCSS (using the LessPHP standard).

Comment: I am using this plugin. I think it could be improved. For example it colors for selectors are green and both properties and values black. However, some properties and values are green. This is confusing and inconsistent.

Comment: I figured out why it was doing it. they have to be `property: value;` with the space. Not `property:value;`. Without the space causes coloring to be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Sublime Text. It's good lightweight editor.

Comment: But little enhanced editing features and a bloated autocomplete (still awesome, though)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Textmate there is a syntax highlighting bundle for LESS:

https://github.com/appden/less.tmbundle

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Eclipse plugin for LESS : http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/ow/eclipse-less.fr.html

Comment: Current version has no option of disabling validation, so file becomes full of errors/warnings, when it uses for example include from other other path.

Comment: It is quite useful (autocompletion of your variables and such), but note that you lose all comments when you format using this plugin in version 1.0.22. And it lacks some of the features of the CSS editor.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax highlighting for LESS is included in [the newest version of rails.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Komodo IDE or Edit for this purpose. It has an add-on named **LESS**

Answer (score 0):

I just tried [Crunch](http://crunchapp.net/) and I like it.
It has syntax highlighting (but no intellisense) and can save as .css.

It requires [Adobe AIR](http://get.adobe.com/air/).