# How can I get IBM WebSphere Commerce 7 to do syntax highlighting for SCSS file?

Tags: css, websphere, syntax-highlighting, sass

I want to start using Sass.  I have everything set up but there is one small hurdle concerning my other team members. I use Sublime Text as my main editor but they are using our WebSphere Commerce Developer IDE 7 as their editor.  I can easily change my syntax highlighting to accommodate the SCSS files, but it appears they cannot.  Even though I recommend it all the time, they aren't willing to change to another editor.

I see that under Window > Preferences > Web, I can change certain syntax highlighting for CSS, JSP, etc.  However, I see no way to tell it to highlight SCSS files as CSS.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Does the editor support adding user defined files for languages/file extensions?  You may be able to find one for Sass that they can download.

Comment: I was hoping that it does.  I just can't figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since IBM WebSphere Commerce runs in an Eclipse IDE, I found a very similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829732/ide-with-syntax-highlight-support-for-less).

Preferences > General > Content Types: find "CSS" entry and add .scss extension.
Then, Preferences > General > Editors > File Assoc: add .scss extension and associate with CSS editor.